# jquery plugin conflict with transform: translateY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im using a lightweight jQuery plugin call leanModal

The code for the plugin is included in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/meqtu354/2/

All the plugin does is, for example in the jsfiddle, when u click on `click to show popup`, the pop up show up and the rest of document get covered by a huge dark transparent div.

But for some reason when I add: `transform: translateY` to my css

https://jsfiddle.net/meqtu354/3/ (check the css, added two selectors)

now when you click `click to show popup`, the overlay (dark transparent div) cover the popup too.

I been reading this for half an hour now, but still cant figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the popup div outside of the st-scroll class:

```
<div id="popup">POPUP</div>

<div class="st-scroll">

    <section></section>
    <script></script>
    <section></section>

</div>
```

I tried it in your fiddle and it worked. When you apply a 3d transform property, I think it merges the div as if it is one object without layers.

Comment: The problem is this is a super simplified version. I really need the popup to be inside there. Cause what happen is whenever a radio button is selected, it will switch to that associated page by pushing the page upward or downward. The popup reside in one of those pages

Comment: Ok, so your javascript appends the overlay to the body tag. Should it append to each section tag individually? Since the transform property merges the sections, which include the popup, it must be a part of that section. Change:

Comment: Oops, I didn't finish... change `$("body").append(overlay);` to `$("#st-panel-1").append(overlay);`. Not sure if that's what you're going for or not.

Comment: Hey thanks, it didnt quite work on my actual code. Maybe If i can understand the problem I can solve it better since I know the original code (as it is too long to post here). So why exactly does adding translateY changes anything. From my understand I'm just shifting everything up. The plugin add a huge overlay covering all the pages, but the pop up should still be on top of that overlay no?

Comment: But once you apply a transform property, your div and everything inside becomes one object. So you can't have part of your object below the overlay and part of it above. You could move the popup outside of the st-scroll div and just control the page and popup independently of one another. I don't want to say it's impossible—there may be a way—but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: hmm thanks I think I'm starting to get it, can you recommend any link for me to read more about this? 
I thought this works like how they resolve z-index. Once they figure out who go ontop among the sibilings, they will group them together and use their parents' z-index to compare with the node in the parents' lvl, and so on n so forth. While I understand your explanation Im still a little bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

you are using adjacent selectors, but not selecting the `<a href="">` you have between #st-control-1 and .st-scroll. that some how is breaking the flow of the CSS. The correct adjacent selector path is:

`#st-control-1:checked ~ #st-panel-1 .st-scroll {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%);
}`

Also, use the vendor pre-fix in your css for these type of properties. hope this helps.

Comment: Is there another way? Because the actual code work like this: There are multiple "pages", each is 100% height, all under `st-scroll`, but in different <section> . Whenever a radio button is click, st-scroll shift up by using translateY, that's why I cant include #st-panel-1. The pop up only reside in page1/#st-panel-1.  Any idea? thanks